# <pre> breaks spoiler on mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web, spoilers

<sub>Originally seen on [this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175391/69850).</sub>

---

The following spoiler

> ```
> code code
> ```
>
> text

on mobile (Chrome 70.0.3538.80, Android 7.1.1) looks like this:

[image: Before click]
[image: After click]

(expected behavior: "text" is shown after click the spoiler, not before)

Comment: Additional info. On iOS it works as expected in both the SE app and mobile Safari. It has the same bug as OP reports in mobile Chrome.

Comment: This is reproducible on Firefox Nightly 65.0a1 on Android and on the mobile view tester (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `M`) on desktop. It doesn’t seem to be browser-dependent since the spoiler is generated by JavaScript.

Comment: Not worth fixing? :( Seeing spoiler without clicking on it is annoying, right?